# Preg_replace find numbers in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, special-characters

Good afternoon,

I have an error in my preg_replace. My string is `Cat-115/Tid-11` and i want find any numbers after `Cat-115/Tid-` and print that

Could you please help me fix this? I am sure, it some basic error, so sorry for that...

My Code :

```
$destination = $_GET['q']; Out ////Cat-115/Tid-11
$numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $destination);
if (strpos($destination, $numbers) !== false) {

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: is "Cat-115/Tid-" a static word ?

Comment: UPDATED........

Comment: sorry , i mean the length of "Cat-115/Tid-" ?

Comment: Just after "Tid-" numbers always Variable !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Cat-115/Tid-` is a fixed string and you want to "find any numbers after Cat-115/Tid- and print that", you could for example use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

Use `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match:

```
$destination = "Cat-115/Tid-11";
preg_match('/Cat-115\/Tid-\K\d+/', $destination, $m);
echo $m[0];
```

Or capture the numbers is a capturing group `(\d+)`

```
preg_match('/Cat-115\/Tid-(\d+)/', $destination, $m);
echo $m[1];
```

[Output](https://3v4l.org/4WBNt)

Comment: Can i find string Instead of numbers after "Cat-115/Tid-" Instead of numbers ??

Comment: @BijanZand The `\d+` matches one or more digits. You could change that to for example `\w+` to match one or more word characters.

Comment: Thanks you very much!